# Universal Link Not Display On Safari Browser In Ios

Tags: swift, apple-app-site-association

I add the configuration of apple app site association like that :

Then this file is uploaded into the host server like that url (https://domain/apple-app-site-association),

From my side add the associated domain in xcode,

The problem when adding the base url domain into safari the universal link popup is not displayed yet.

Comment: And this configuration the apple app site association
 

{ "applinks": { "apps": [], "details": [ { "appID": "TeamID.packagename", "paths": ["*"] } ] } } –